# Как удалить объект из массива Redux?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, redux

Пишу небольшой магазинчик и по нажатию кнопки нужно удалить элемент с подходящими id и size, проект делаю по референсу и не могу понять, почему у него работает, а у меня нет?

```
const initialState = {
  items: []
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
     //тут ещё редюсеры для добавления и тд, не стал их сюда добавлять
     removeItem(state, action) {
        state.items.filter((obj) => obj.id !== action.payload.id && obj.size !== action.payload.size)
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил, надо изменить строчку

```
state.items = state.items.filter((obj) => obj.id !== action.payload.id && obj.size !== action.payload.size)
```